# difference in the format of output between datetime and datetime2(3) data types when converted to varchar with style 114

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime-format

There is a difference between the format of DateTime and DateTime2(3) when they are converted to varchar with style 114. The example is as follows:

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime=GETDATE()
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME2(3)=GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date1, 114),CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date2,114)
```

The output of the above SQL statements is:

```
14:47:33:820   14:47:33.820
```

[db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=041588148e67164c1485b29fc09cd2c2)

So, we can see the difference in the output is ":" in the case of DateTime whereas "." in the case of DateTime2(3).
Is there any solution to get the ":" in the output in the case of datetime2(3)?

Comment: This is clearly a bug, and Stack Overflow isn't a website for reporting bugs; for SQL Server use the [Azure feedback forums](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server). *Really*, however, you should be formatting the value in your presentation layer, not the RDBMS, but what's wrong with `REPLACE`?

Comment: I was thinking about any other style which can give the ":" as output

Comment: The colon usage is logically a mistake. The colon should separate different units of measurement, not fractional parts of the same unit.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is unexplainable; as a workaround, you can use the `FORMAT` function to [format the date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

```sql
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME     = SYSDATETIME()
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME2(3) = SYSDATETIME()

SELECT
    @date1,
    @date2, 
    FORMAT(@date1, 'HH:mm:ss:fff'),
    FORMAT(@date2, 'HH:mm:ss:fff')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can `CAST @date2 AS DATETIME` before convert to varchar if you want to get the ":" in the output in the case of datetime2(3)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date1, 114),CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(@date2 AS DATETIME),114)
```

Comment: Be aware that `DATETIME` has a 3.33ms accuracy where as `DATETIME2(n)` has 100ns - so you will loose some precision doing this conversion. That *could be* a problem - or not - depending on your use case - just something to be aware of ! If it is - maybe it would be easier to just do a string replace on the result string instead .....

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, format `113` seems to use the colon correctly, so you can use:

```
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), @date2, 113), 12)
```

Note the use of a length with `VARCHAR()`.  My advice is to **never** use string types in SQL Server without a length.  The default length varies by context and not including an explicit length can introduce a hard-to-debug error.